# Spring Cloud Stream remove x-exception-stacktrace from DLQ Message

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

we try to remove the "x-exception-stacktrace" from the DLQ messages to make the footprint of republish messages smaller.

We use the default spring mechanism with

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default:
        consumer:
          maxAttempts: 1 
      bindings:
        foo:
          destination: bar
      rabbit:
        default:
          binder: service_rabbit
          consumer:
            contentType: application/json
            republishToDlq: true
            autoBindDlq: true
            dlqTtl: 1000
            dlq-dead-letter-exchange:
```

If a message is repeated multiple times, the "x exception stacktrace" is always copied and the message becomes even longer. We also log everything so the header is useless to use. Is there a way to remove the header?

We try to increase the frameMaxHeadroom but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `frameMaxHeadRoom` property should work. I just tested it and it worked for me...

[image]

However, there is a bug; if `frameMaxHeadroom` is too large, it is ignored, it must be less than `RabbitUtils.getMaxFrame(connectionFactory)` to work; we should assume 0 available for the trace if it is larger.

In my case, that value is 131072; with the example above (that worked), I used `frame-max-head-room: 131000`; leaving just 72 bytes for the trace.

It should be possible to add a `MessagePostProcessor` to the binder's template for DLQs, in `RabbitTemplate.setBeforePublishPostProcessors()`, to manipulate the headers, but that is not currently possible.

Please open a new feature issue on GitHub (`spring-cloud-stream`).